# Erro HttpWebRequest C#

Tags: c#, http-request

Estou fazendo uma requisição numa URL e ao tentar pegar a resposta, recebo o seguinte erro:

> A conexão subjacente estava fechada: Erro inesperado em um envio.

A questão é que essa instrução funcionava normalmente.

Abaixo o código:

```
var httpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
{
    string json = "{ 'nl': { 'NL': '" + numeroLogico + "', 'CPF_CNPJ': '" + cnpj.Trim() + "', 'Bandeiras': [" + bandeiras + "], 'InativarBandeira': '" + inativarBandeiras + "', 'InativarLogico': '" + inativarLogico + "' } }";
    string jsonFinal = json.Replace("'", "\"");

    streamWriter.Write(json);
    streamWriter.Flush();
    streamWriter.Close();
}

var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
```

Após a solicitação da resposta, recebo o erro. Não sei o que fazer, já ví de tudo e nada funciona.

Comment: Se testar a requisição por outro lugar funciona normal?

Comment: @LINQ sim. Faço a chamada via postman por exemplo e funciona. essa conexão funcionou por meses, e parou sem nenhuma explicação.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coloque essa linha depois de criar o WebRequest

```
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```